# Clickhouse deleting rows unexpectedly

Tags: java, clickhouse

I'm trying to learn clickhouse and ways of working with it in Java. I decided to use its native java client. I implemented, the following flow: delete data by some condition and then insert another data (part of which may match the condition in delete statement).
I'm using ALTER TABLE ... DELETE statement to clean out data and then INSERT INTO ... for data insertion. But calling this queries one after another leads me to deletion of new inserted data. I am a little bit stuck in finding the answer why this is happening.
So, again:

1. ALTER TABLE ... DELETE <-- which is synchronous
2. INSERT INTO

Leads me to deletion of inserted data. I use ClickHouse 23.12.1.47 with java client of 0.5.0 version.

Table schema:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
    name        String,
    surname     String,
    system String
) ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree() ORDER BY (system);
```

I've tried to use lightweight delete but it appeared to be async

Comment: ALTER TABLE ... DELETE <-- which is synchronous

you are wrong, by default this is async, use `SETTINGS mutations_sync=2` for synchronous execution


Do you try to insert the same data in INSERT INTO query? 

ReplicatedMergeTree store in ZK checksums of last 100 blocks, and silent ignore new blocks with the same checksum

This behavior required for corner case when client disconnected before receive OK response and try to retry.

Answer (score 1):

I see, that you're using replicated merge tree. Every operation on replicated trees are async, so you're alter table query is running somewhere in future, so that's why inserted data can be deleted after insertion(
consider using non-replicated merge trees!
hope my answer is helpful for you

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this feature, you helped me a lot!